# How do I make a blank empty cell in a table clickable and make it display something on another table using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's an image to show what I mean:

[image]

For example on clicking the space for 12th august, I want the events and time of the events to be displayed on the table below.
(The event and time is pre defined)

Comment: You should add your HTML and JS (if any) here to the question, because your image looks like one of many Calendar libraries.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```js
function showevent(){
    var evtable = document.getElementById("eventtable");
    evtable.classList.add("active");
    var row= evtable.insertRow(1);
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "Aug 12 2020";
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = "Javascript";
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = "10am";
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = "12pm";
}
```

```css
table,td,th{
  border:1px solid #111;
  padding:10px;
}
.event{display:none;}
#eventtable{display:none;margin-top:10px;}
#eventtable.active{display:table;}
```

```html
<table id="calendar">
  <tr><td colspan="7" style="text-align:center;">August 2020</td>
  <tr class="weekdays">
    <th scope="col">Sun</th>
    <th scope="col">Mon</th>
    <th scope="col">Tue</th>
    <th scope="col">Wed</th>
    <th scope="col">Thu</th>
    <th scope="col">Fri</th>
    <th scope="col">Sat</th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="days">
    <td class="day other-month">
      <div class="date">31</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day other-month">
      <div class="date"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="day other-month">
      <div class="date"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="day other-month">
      <div class="date"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="day other-month">
      <div class="date"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">1</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">3</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">4</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">5</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">6</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">7</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">8</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">9</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">10</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">11</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day" id="onetwo" onClick="showevent()">12
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">13</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">14</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">15</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">16</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">17</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">18</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">19</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">20</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">21</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">22</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">23</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">24</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">25</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">26</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">27</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">28</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">29</div>
    </td>
    <td class="day">
      <div class="date">30</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>
<table id="eventtable">
    <tr>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>subject name</td>
        <th>start time</td>
        <th>end time</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Iam hardcoded value. if the question make changes to click every td has a event.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for! ;)